# Average response time on Grafana from Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am trying to find the average response time of all the URLs in Grafana,

The below query not returning any data, what am I doing wrong here?

```
    avg by (uri) (rate(http_server_requests_seconds_sum{app_name="$app",
                  namespace="$namespace", uri!~".*actuator.*|/health|root"}[1m]) 
   /rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{app_name="$app",
                  namespace="$namespace", uri!~".*actuator.*|/health|root"}[1m]))
```

The data is collected via a micrometer.

Comment: You aren't getting any result because the first part is eliminating all labels except the uri, while the dividend is keeping all the labels. Since there isn't a perfect match of labels anymore, Prometheus discards them. @pulak's solution below with using sum fixes that

Answer (score 17):

If you want to get the average then you should divide the _sum by the _count counter. If your labels are ok, then you will get data(if there any) by below PromQL.

```
sum by (uri) (rate(http_server_requests_seconds_sum{app_name="$app", 
            namespace="$namespace", uri!~".*actuator.*|/health|root"}[1m])) / 
sum by (uri) (rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{app_name="$app",
            namespace="$namespace", uri!~".*actuator.*|/health|root"}[1m]))
```

Comment: you can also use `increase` function instead of `rate` ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé You will get the same numbers, yes. But people prefer `rate` because of counting RPS.